# DynamoDB deleteItem is not getting mocked using Mockito

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

Below is the code I am trying to mock.

`DeleteItemOutcome outcome = table.deleteItem(deleteItem);`

When I am trying to write the testcase for the above code, I am getting credentials not found error

Test Code:

```
DynamoDB dynamoDb = Mockito.mock(DynamoDB.class);
Table mockTable = Mockito.mock(Table.class);
DeleteItemOutcome itemOutcome = Mockito.mock(DeleteItemOutcome.class); 
        Mockito.when(mockTable.deleteItem(Mockito.any(DeleteItemSpec.class))).thenReturn(itemOutcome);
Mockito.when(dynamoDb.getTable(anyString())).thenReturn(mockTable);
ResponseEntity<String> resp = Service.functionName('123');
```

Error:

```
2023-12-27 20:58:42.733 ERROR 14376 --- [           main] .r.c.a.c.m.Service: Error deleting Customer for personID ->123 -> Status Code: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: To use assume role profiles the aws-java-sdk-sts module must be on the class path., com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@391e85df: profile file cannot be null, com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@2d3111a1: Failed to connect to service endpoint: ]
```

I also added the below lines as a part of my test code but still it didn't yield any result

```
System.setProperty("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID","example");
System.setProperty("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY","example");
```

Please suggest what needs to be fixed. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using `aws configure`. I'm not sure if mocking the client requires credentials, double check your not calling the API.